# Categories from Outlook for contacts in iPhone

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, ms-office

I use Outlook and have my contacts under categories, e.g. home, clients, family, etc.

When I sync from Outlook to my iPhone I get all the contacts, but I cannot find the categories.

How can I search in my iPhone the contacts for categories I have in Outlook, for example 'family'?

Answer (score 1):

Go into Contacts.

On the upper left corner, select "Groups". If you have any additional Contact files, they should be available to view there. Note that this only applies to Exchange accounts and local Groups more than likely will not show.